# How to refer to columns in a table via a character variable in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably a fairly simple question, but couldn't find anything specific for it.
Lets say I have the following data frame

```
A
     Hello World
   1   5     6
   2   5     6
```

If you want to fetch the the values from the Hello column you would usually just do it with

```
A$Hello
```

But is there a way to fetch the column values with a predefined variable like this?

```
col <- "Hello"
A$col
```

The latter returns NULL for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  hello world
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     6
2     5     7
> col = 'hello'
> A[[col]]
[1] 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `A[col]`:

```
## Hello
##   <dbl>
## 1     5
## 2     5
```

Essentially, just uses another form of indexing.  This works because `col` is a string.

Comment: this was useful, but not using double bracket syntax actually yields a table rather than a numerical vector like A$Hello does.

Comment: that's true - sorry I didn't completely think through what you might want (i.e. data frame versus vector)